Splunk Search that uses JSON Parameters
I have a search query that shows server health status.
The servers are hard-coded in the search query, currently.
But, I want have the server data read from a JSON file.
JSON data:
hosts: 
  - name: server_1.company.com
  - name: server_2.company.com
  - name: server_3.company.com
  - name: server_4.company.com

Search Query:
index=app_* 

| WHERE host IN ("server_1", "server_2", "server_3", "server_4")

| eval server_status=case( 
                  match(_raw, "HTTP/1.1\" 200"), "OK",
                  match(_raw, "HTTP/1.1\" 404"), "NOT OK",
                  true(), "ERROR")

| eval server_type=case(host IN ("server_1", "server_2", "server_3", "server_4"), "processor")  

| table _time, host, server_status, server_type


If you filter out by host at the beginning why would your server_type logic need the same condition?

Consider using Splunk Lookup table (CSV) instead of JSON.
